# running batch files from C# takes too much time

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I am running a batch file from c# align.bat it is taking more than 40 seconds
but when i run the same batch file manually it takes less than 2 seconds. what changes is needed to eliminate the extra time consumed?

```
            string comnd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Process batchProcess = new Process();
            batchProcess.StartInfo.FileName = comnd + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "align.bat";
            batchProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = comnd;
            //batchProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            batchProcess.Start();
            batchProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: instead of executing bat. you can execute cmd and give string content of batch file as CMD parameters. so it will be running same as bat file. can you try it ?

Comment: This should not happen. Something else than the code you show  must be the reason..

Comment: well, what does the batch file do? how about posting its code?

Comment: Why would you use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and then *manually* combine paths when `Path` already has methods for doing that?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard _"...when i run the same batch file `manually` it takes less than `2 seconds`"_

Comment: batchcommands = "srec_cat filename1.extn -fill 0xFF -within filename1.extn -range-padding 4 -output_block_size 16 -address_length 4 -output filename2.extn";

i tried like this Process.Start("CMD.exe",batchcommands); 
it takes more than 40 seconds to open cmd.exe and also it won't execute the batchcommands

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
if i give hard codded complete path also it takes same time. both cases my functionality works but time consumed is high. i see its taking time to open cmd.exe

Comment: How about starting another exe? How about `Process.Start("cmd.exe");`? Is it quick?

Comment: @cactuaroid no It again takes same time 40 sec for Process.Start("cmd.exe") after batchProcess.Start();[that is 40 sec + 40 sec totally]

Comment: So it is not the issue about batch file. How about like this `Process.Start("taskmgr.exe");`?

Comment: @cactuaroid it takes 40 seconds for Process.Start("taskmgr.exe) too

Comment: Did you study [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326949(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: This seems very odd. Open task manager to see if you ran out of physical memory, high CPU load, or high HDD/SSD load. If you have access to a profiler, try running it to see if something is horribly wrong. Try creating and testing an new empty C# program with only Process.Start() - it probably won't lag. Your best bet then is to make a copy of your program and start removing parts of it until it no longer lags and then try to determine which part of it causes the issue. It can be anything from memory leak to bugged driver. Can't your environment cause problems? permission problem? network?

Comment: @JackWhite I don't see any run out of physical memory or cpu or HDD. I tried in different devices still same 40 seconds. also a new project still same issue.

Comment: I'm honestly baffled. Do you have any kind of antivirus/antimalware installed? Or maybe some other security application? If so could you turn it off for a moment and then test again?

Comment: @JackWhite there is antivirus but i can't turn off as it is controlled by company. Let try in my personal laptop but final application must work in company devices. 
Can we do it without turning off the antivirus?

Comment: Company? That may be a clue. So far you did all tests on company-supplied computers, right? Same anti-virus on both? I suspect then anti-virus might look your program up in an online database. It has zero matches - highly suspicious. It decides your EXE may be a dropper and silently runs whatever is executed in a sandbox for a while, decides it's ok, and runs it normally.

Comment: @JackWhite Thank you yes you are right this is because of antivirus or the company network. It works fine in my personal device

Comment: You are welcome. It is not really useful to try to fight the antivirus. Instead try to get your admin to whitelist your program or at least disable sandboxing for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing revealed that the issue was caused by an anti-malware software suite installed on all of employer's computers.

This software probably detects a new piece of software as an unknown dropper and at first runs anything it starts silently in a sandbox before starting it normally.

Solution should then be to whitelist the program(s) causing issues and/or disable sandboxing.